# What does the IN query search for?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

How to search for rows where a `varchar` field contains some predefined integers?

ex.

```
SELECT * FROM `map` WHERE `product` IN (2, 3, 4)
```

If all rows contain other integers, other than these three, the query returns an empty result.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same as

```
WHERE product = 2 OR product = 3 OR product = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `map` WHERE `product` IN (2, 3, 4)
```

The in is essentially a short hand way of checking if product is = to 2 or =3 or =4.

As Tjati stated, it can be rewritten as

```
SELECT * FROM `map` WHERE product = 2 OR product = 3 OR product = 4
```

It is typically good practice to do this to improve readability of your SQL.

A good link to practice or to better understand this concept is:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in

This is just a module off of the popular w3schools website:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

A small example directly from mysql official page. (copied here incase links die)

Here you can see the full table.

`mysql> SELECT * FROM employee_tbl;`

`+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                350 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Now, suppose based on the above table you want to display records with daily_typing_pages equal to 250 and 220 and 170. This can be done using OR conditions as follows

`mysql>SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    ->WHERE daily_typing_pages= 250 OR

    ->daily_typing_pages= 220 OR  daily_typing_pages= 170;`

`+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)`

**Same can be achieved using IN clause as follows:**

`mysql> SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    -> WHERE daily_typing_pages IN ( 250, 220, 170 );`

`+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)`

Comment: ex.:

'product' fields in all rows:

1,2,3,4
1,3,4
1,2
1,2,4

meaning all the rows contain the "1"

we are searching for rows where 2 AND 3 AND 4 are present, no matter if they contain the 1

Answer (score 0):

This is basically IN clause to replace many OR conditions

```
SELECT * FROM `map` WHERE `product` = 2 OR `product` = 3 OR `product` = 4
```

Comment: ex.:  
  
'product' fields in all rows:  

1,2,3,4
1,3,4
1,2
1,2,4

meaning all the rows contain the "1"

we are searching for rows where 2 AND 3 AND 4 are present, no matter if they contain the 1